# how to create jar with dependencies for rest api

Tags: java, rest, cxf

```
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        sf.setResourceClasses(CalcREST.class);
        sf.setResourceProvider(CalcREST.class,
            new SingletonResourceProvider(new CalcREST()));
        sf.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/api/");

        sf.create();
        System.out.println("Server ready...");
```

If I run the code above from the console it works fine. After creating a jar with dependencies using the assembly plugin I get the error below. If I remove the http from the set address string the server is created but, I can't access the api. What am I missing? Your help will be really appreciated.

> Mar 05, 2021 9:11:34 AM org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory getDestination
> SEVERE: Cannot find any registered HttpDestinationFactory from the Bus.
> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:216)
> at App.(App.java:34)
> at App.main(App.java:41)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot find any registered HttpDestinationFactory from the Bus.
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(HTTPTransportFactory.java:276)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:85)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.(ServerImpl.java:64)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:170)
> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

The CXF jars contain important files in a `META-INF` folder. Most probably those have not been merged in your jar with dependencies.

Please list the contents of your jar with dependencies or a link to a reproducer to allow further analysis.